# Как в потоке данных объединить буквы образуя слово?

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть массив слов. Я хочу его в потоке `stream` немного обработать. Абстрактная задача.

#### Задача:

- Преобразовать все слова в нижний регистр
- Получить первую букву из слова
- Объединить эти буквы от 3-4 образуя слово

Используя потоки, можно ли это реализовать?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class WordsStream {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String contents = "Гештальт, в первом приближении, социально аннигилирует закон. Психоанализ отражает латентный генезис.";
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\PL+"));

        Stream<String> stringStream = list.stream()
                // Преобразуем все в нижний регистр
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                // Получаем первую букву слова
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
                // Объединить буквы от 3-4 составив "слова"
        ;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringStream.toArray()));
    }
}
```

**output** на текущий момент:

```
[г, в, п, п, с, а, з, п, о, л, г]
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

```
[гвпп, сазп, олг]
```

Comment: под потоками вы понимаете parallelStream()?

Comment: @Dred если можно через него `parallelStream()` то окей, он ведь тоже как поток.

Comment: Не, может вы имете в виду Thread :-)

Comment: @Dred `Thread` это вроде как просто поток, нить. А тут `Stream`

Comment: Оно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057690/java-stream-collect-every-n-elements?

Comment: @Chubatiy возможно ответ от туда можно как не будь, преобразовать сюда. Но это не прямо "оно" :). Спасибо, посмотрю, там много интересных решений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На базе исходного кода и [данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057913/3432401) получается так:

```
String contents = "Гештальт, в первом приближении, социально аннигилирует закон. Психоанализ отражает латентный генезис.";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\PL+"));

int size = 4;

Object[] result = IntStream.range(0, (list.size() + size - 1) / size)
                           .mapToObj(index -> list.subList(index * size, Math.min(size * (index + 1), list.size())))
                           .map(subList -> subList.stream()
                                                  .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase())
                                                  .collect(Collectors.joining()))
                           .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

- Создаём поток с номерами итоговых групп букв
- Получаем подсписки из исходного списка
- Каждый подсписок слов преобразуем, беря первую букву каждого слова с приведением её к нижнему регистру и объединяя итоговые бувы в строку

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class WordsStream {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String contents = "Гештальт, в первом приближении, социально аннигилирует закон. Психоанализ отражает латентный генезис.";
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\PL+"));

        String string = list.stream()
                // Преобразуем все в нижний регистр
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                // Получаем первую букву слова
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
                // Объединить буквы от 3-4 составив "слова"
        ;

        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы тут просто все объединяете: `гвппсазполг`

Comment: а по какому принципу вы хотите объеденить? что такое 3-4 буквы?

Comment: смотрите ожидаемый результат, скажем берем начальные буквы, объединяем идем дальше, что-то типо того.

Comment: по 4 буквы, а в последнем выводе все остальное (остается 3)? или какой-то другой принцип?

Comment: можно и так, просто интересует сам принцип.